# Extract data from php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, moodle

I have the following `array` in my `Moodle` `plugin`:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 32
        [sessionid] => 5
        [sessiontimezone] => CET
        [timestart] => 1464071400
        [timefinish] => 1464102000 ) 

    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 33
        [sessionid] => 5
        [sessiontimezone] => CET
        [timestart] => 1465281000
        [timefinish] => 1465311600 )
)
```

How to get the `data`. Right now, when I make:

```
$pluginsessiondates = $DB->get_record('plugin_sessions', array('id'=>$sessionid));
```

I get only data from the `frist` `array` `[0]`

How to `get` the data from every `array` `key` and then the `single` `values`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Moodle DB functions are for getting data out of the database, rather than from an array somewhere inside your plugin.

If you have an array somewhere, then you can get fields from it by writing:

```
echo $myarray[0]->id;
echo $myarray[1]->id;
etc.
```

If you are not trying to get data out of an existing array and want, instead, to get it out of the database, then $DB->get_record() will, as its name implies, get you only a single record, whereas $DB->get_records() will get you all the matching records:

```
$sessions = $DB->get_records('plugin_sessions', array('sessionid' => $sessionid));
foreach ($sessions as $session) {
    echo $session->id;
}
```